# LateError (LateInitializationError: Field '_userLocation@227004938' has not been initialized.)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a simple location tracking application with Flutter. My goal is to learn the location system.

First, `main.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:phone_charge_map/firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:phone_charge_map/src/screens/main_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:phone_charge_map/src/providers/main_provider.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  initFirebase();
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => MainProvider(),
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

initFirebase() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late MainProvider mainProvider;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getUserLocation();
  }

  Future<void> _getUserLocation() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
      desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.medium,
    );
    mainProvider = Provider.of<MainProvider>(context, listen: false);
    mainProvider.updateUserLocation(position);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "PChargerMap",
      home: MainScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

`main_screen.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';
import 'package:phone_charge_map/src/providers/main_provider.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainScreen> createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Consumer<MainProvider>(
        builder: (context, provider, child) {
          return FlutterMap(
            options: MapOptions(
              center: LatLng(
                provider.userLocation.latitude,
                provider.userLocation.longitude,
              ),
              zoom: 3.2,
              maxZoom: 18.0,
            ),
            children: [
              TileLayer(
                urlTemplate: 'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                userAgentPackageName: 'speedev.phone_charge_map',
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`main_provider.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class MainProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  late Position _userLocation;

  Position get userLocation => _userLocation;

  void updateUserLocation(Position newPosition) {
    _userLocation = newPosition;
    print(_userLocation);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

My goal here is to get location information as soon as the user opens the app. Then redirect to `MainScreen` and show its location. This is exactly my aim. However, I am getting `LateError (LateInitializationError: Field '_userLocation@227004938' has not been initialized.)` error in `main_provider.dart`.

As far as I understand, I am getting such an error because I redirected without obtaining location information. I couldn't solve this problem. Can you help me? I'm grateful already.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement the code that is responsible for determining the location in a future provider. The Future Provider returns a Loading-, error- or data state. This could look like this:

```
final userLocationProvider = FutureProvider<Position>((ref) async {
  Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
    desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.medium,
  );
  return position;
});
```

if no data is available yet, the loading state is executed in the widget. Here you can display a loading animation. when the state is loaded, the data part is automatically displayed. if there is an error, the error part is displayed.

```
//read the Provider
Consumer(
final userLocationAsyncValue = watch(userLocationProvider);

return userLocationAsyncValue.when(
      data: (position) {
        // Here you can visualize your Data (stored in position)
        return Text('Current position: ${position.latitude}, ${position.longitude}');
      },
      loading: () => CircularProgressIndicator(), //here you can show your Loadingscreen

      error: (error, stackTrace) => Text('$error'), //here you can show your error message
    );
  },
)
```